# jQuery select on div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a small text editor, and for that, I would like a similar effect when a user selects some text as here: http://raphaelcruzeiro.github.io/jquery-notebook/

I was thinking of using the jQuery select event, but I can't seem to get it working on divs, only on input fields.

```
<!--<input type="text" class="writing-area" value="foo bar">-->
<div class="writing-area">foo bar</div>

<script>
$(".writing-area").select(function(){
    alert("Text marked!");
  });
</script>
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/WL2nz/
The outcommented HTML works just fine, but the div version does not.

What am I doing wrong? Can select not be used on divs?

Comment: REad this : http://api.jquery.com/select/ `:)` `The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to <input type="text"> fields and <textarea> boxes.` and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Answer (score 0):

The MDN reference for the [select event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select) says that the HTML5 spec only defined the select event for inputs and textareas.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/select/), "this event is limited to  fields and  boxes".

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery page (http://api.jquery.com/select/) for the .select() function:

"The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to  fields and  boxes."

To get the effect you are look for, have you considered onmouseover or onclick with a clickable element?

In addition, the Dojo Toolkit is one place where you can get a nice tooltip to craft something similar to what you are looking for: click [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dialogs_tooltips/)

Answer (score 0):

All answers are correct, but the plugin you have linked to, does it this way:

After using the keyboard or the mouse (`keyup`,`focus`,`mouseup`...) the plugin checks if something is select. If something is selected the bubble pops up.

The code is [here](https://github.com/raphaelcruzeiro/jquery-notebook/blob/master/src/js/jquery.notebook.js)

Answer (score 0):

we highlighted the color of div text when hovers it and remove the color while non-hover the text.

```
$(".writing-area").hover(function(){
$(".writing-area").css('color','red');
 },function(){
$(".writing-area").css('color','');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WL2nz/4/